# HTML Table - Sticky right and left column and scrollbar limited to middle column width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with three columns, and I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. The first and last column should be sticky one to the left and another to the right and should have smaller width than the middle column.
2. I want to keep all the headers sticky (always visible) when scrolling x or y
3. I would like to limit the scrollbar to only appear within the width of the middle column.
   When the scrollbar appears, I want it to scroll the entire middle column, not just one cell.

I have tried multiple things, but I cannot come with something very clean.

Any idea how to achieve this nicely?

Could grid css or flex be an option? I know they are not to be used for tabular data, but maybe for this thing can make sense!? I would prefer table though.

```css
div {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100px;
  text-wrap: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
}

th {
  background-color: red;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: grey;
}

td:last-child,
th:last-child {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

th:first-child,
th:last-child {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width"
  >
  <title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Property</th>
          <th>Value</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
            has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
            type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
            leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
            release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
            software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;laalalalal</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
            has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
            type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
            leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
            release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
            software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
            has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
            type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
            leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
            release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
            software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```